# How to Scroll the text in label automatically

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, nstimer

I have an array , data of which 'm displaying on scrollview using UILabel. I can scroll right and left. But I want to add one more feature in that which is automatic scrolling of the label text on scrollview. That means even if I do not scroll I want it to move by itself.
My code for scrolling is as below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _scrollView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 300, 0, 300);

    NSMutableArray *items=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A walk to remember",@"The Last song",@"The Notebook",@"Dear John",@"The Longest Ride",nil];

    CGFloat y = 10;
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,y,800, 25)];

    for(int i=0;i<[items count];i++){
          y+=20;        
         NSString* lab=[items objectAtIndex:i];
        _label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lab=[items componentsJoinedByString:@" | "];
        NSLog(@"label:%@",lab);
        [self.label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [self.label setText:lab];     
    }   

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timer)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; 

    //[_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:NSMakeRange(0,0,0.0) animated:YES]; 
    [_scrollView addSubview:_label];
    [UIView commitAnimations];    

    _scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width*[items count], _scrollView.frame.size.height);   
    }
```

timer code:

```
-(void)timer {

[self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", self.label.text]];
```

}

Please help me how could I make the label text move horizontally. Thanks for any help

Comment: I think it is code for adding the label on scroll view. There is no code for animation. Can you please add time code?

Comment: this code makes my text move automatically now. But From left to right. I wanted it to be moved from right to left and repeat the things again.

Comment: Simply try to use [AutoScrollLabel](https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel). This will help you....

Comment: Thank you so much N J Gadhiya , It worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fairly horrible way to implement scrolling if I may so so! You're scrolling by inserting incremental spaces to the left of the string. There is a much easier way to do this!

- Keep your code that adds the UILabels to your scroll view
- Get rid of the NSTimer stuff
- Add a basic UIView animation to animate the scrollview's content offset.

Something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        _scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-50.0f, 0.0f);
    } completion:nil];
```

This will slide the whole scrollview left by 50 points over 0.3secs. You can play around with the settings.

btw, typically you'd create the UILabels in viewDidLoad (as you have it) but put the animation in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear

Have had another look at your code. I thought you were adding multiple UILabels to your uiscrollview but actually you're adding just one with a long text string.

You can simplify your code to set up the label quite a bit, then implement the scrolling animation per the below.

```
NSMutableArray *items=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A walk to remember",@"The Last song",@"The Notebook",@"Dear John",@"The Longest Ride",nil];

CGFloat y = 10;
self.label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,y,800, 25)];
[self.label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[self.label setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[self.label setText: [items componentsJoinedByString:@" | "]];
```

EDIT

To your question about how to show the whole line scrolling and then repeating, there are a couple of steps here.

- Make the UILabel wide enough to take all the text on a single line - i.e. increase the width so that it's big enough to fit all the text. You can do this by trial and error or use `(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size`

to get the size. You call `CGSize size = self.label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGFloatMax, self.label.frame.size.height)` to get the size then apply this to the label's frame:

```
CGRect frame = self.label.frame;
frame.size.width = size.width; //calculated above with sizeThatFits
self.label.frame = frame; //update the frame
```

- Now scroll the scrollview by the full width. So the animateWithDuration code would become:

  _scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-size.width, 0.0f);
- The final step is how to make it restart once it's got to the end. Not sure what effect you want here? Should it jump back to the start? (if so set the contentOffset x to zero), or continue scrolling? (if so, use a trick like adding a second UILabel at the end of the first.

BTW, if what you're after is a simple scrolling text like a banner on a webpage, then I suggest you don't bother with the scrollview at all. Instead add the UILabel to self.view and then animate the UILabel's frame origin directly.

Comment: But this won't make my text move automatically

Comment: It should do - have you tried it? Maybe make it move slower (change the 0.3f to 5.0f) and further (change the -50.0f to -200.0f). Another way to do this would be to move the UILabel's frame to the left.

Comment: thank you. But to move the string from the starting to ending and once it ends I wants start from the beginning again.  What do I need to do for that?

Comment: yeah I changed the points. But it ll go till the half and stop. If I click on that , It ll come to the position and will be static

Comment: Have added some more to my response - hth

Comment: thank you so much. I have few doubts. In CGSize size = self.label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGFloatMax, self.label.frame.size.height), what does "CGFloatMax".Any value I need to put?

Comment: For restart I want it to jump back and start again automatic scrolling. How will I do that?

Comment: Hi, the way that sizeThatFits works is you give it constraints. We don't want to constrain the width (it can be as big as needed) so we pass a large value for this constraint. CGFloatMax is the biggest value a CGFloat can be.

Comment: Suggest you use the completion part of the animation code. Change `completion: nil` to `completion:^(BOOL finished) {[ self.scrollView.contentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)] };`

Comment: when I tried putting completion: code "[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-300.0f, 0.0f);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {[ self.scrollView.contentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)]};];"
 it gives me 3 error 1. Bad receiver type 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') 2. Expected ']' 3.Expected expression

Comment: Sorry, it should be: `self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);` I think I'll have to leave you with the rest of this as I need to do some other work!

Comment: thank you. I have done this change. But still 'm getting an error Expected Expression